# Exit time of a stochastic process defined by a SDE

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a "small particle" trapped in a $n$-dimensional potential. We will assume the dynamics of $\mathcal{P}$ are well described by the stochastic differential equation
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d} x_t & = v_t \mathrm{d}t \\
m\mathrm{d}  v_t& = -\nabla \Psi(x_t) \mathrm{d}t -\gamma v_t \mathrm{d}t + \sigma \mathrm{d} W_t
\end{align*}
where $x_t$ and $v_t$ are the position and velocity vectors, $\Psi(x)$ is a bell-shaped potential with a single minimum at $\Psi(0)$ and $W_t$ is a vector Wiener process. Now define the energy of the particle as
\begin{align}\label{eq:energy}
h(x_t, v_t) = \Psi(x_t) + \frac{1}{2}mv_t^2.
\end{align}
I am interested in calculating the time it takes for $\mathcal{P}$ to reach a certain energy $r$, i.e., the stopping time
$$
\tau_h = \inf\{ t \geq 0: h(x_t, v_t) = r \}.
$$
Calculating $\mathbb{E}(\tau_h)$ would be enough for now. So far I have tried calculating
\begin{align}\label{eq:en_evolution}
h(x_t, v_t) = h(x_0, v_0) + \int_0^t \mathrm{d} h(x_s, v_s),
\end{align}
and then, by taking expected values, I hoped I'd be able to solve by $\mathbb{E}(\tau_h)$. With the Wiener process I got the right and well-known result of the exit time from a ball of radius $r$ (this is, in fact, a naive way of using Dynkin's formula), but with the process I described before I didn't get too far. Assuming the initial conditions are distributed according to the invariant (Gibbs) measure, one gets, of course, that
$$
\mathbb{E}[h(x_t, v_t)] = \mathbb{E}[\Psi(x_t)] + \frac{1}{2}k_B T,
$$
which is true, and reassuring, but not very useful, since we lost $\mathbb{E}(\tau_h)$.

I'm not especially used to calculations like this, so any suggestions of "tricks" and/or common techniques for calculating hitting times would be appreciated. I would also be grateful for any references where similar exit time calculations are performed (for non trivial processes).